# exclamation mark in sql xml

Tags: sql, xml

I have a problem trying add a element with an illegal character.  I have the following SQL

```
SELECT  
'en-GB' AS '@xml:lang',
'20120217164611.1712._3FO0ZXYQ3@GBRAPPCHL1' AS '@payloadID',
'2012-02-17T16:46:11' AS '@timestamp',
'1.2.014' AS '@version',
  ( SELECT
     ( SELECT /* FROM */
        (SELECT 'TecSolExchangeID' AS 'Credential/@domain', 33333 AS 'Credential/Identity'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
        (SELECT 'name' AS 'Credential/@domain', 'Test Limited' AS 'Credential/Identity'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
      FOR XML PATH('From'), TYPE ),
     ( SELECT /* TO */
        (SELECT 'TecSolExchangeID' AS 'Credential/@domain', 66666 AS 'Credential/Identity'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
        (SELECT 'name' AS 'Credential/@domain', 'Test Company' AS 'Credential/Identity'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
      FOR XML PATH('To'), TYPE ),
     ( SELECT /* SENDER */
        (SELECT 'TecSolExchangeID' AS 'Credential/@domain', 13041 AS 'Credential/Identity', '' AS 'Credential/SharedSecret'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE), ' cXML Link v1.3.0' AS 'UserAgent'
      FOR XML PATH('Sender'), TYPE )
   FROM TEST2.PORDER
   WHERE POHNUM_0 = '2011302POH00000002'
     FOR XML PATH('Header'),TYPE )
     ,   ( SELECT 'production' AS '@deploymentMode',
     ( SELECT
                   ( SELECT /* ShipNoticeHeader */
              (SELECT ''
               FOR XML PATH(''),
                   TYPE)
            FOR XML PATH('ShipNoticeHeader'),
                TYPE ),
           ( SELECT  '' AS '@domain',
              '' as 'CarrierIdentfier',
                      ''AS 'ShipmentIdentifier'
            FOR XML PATH('ShipControl'),
                TYPE ),
                                 (SELECT /* Ship Notice Portion */
                    (SELECT '1;29117/42' AS 'DocumentReference/@PayLoadID',
                            '' AS 'DocumentReference'
                     FOR XML PATH('OrderReference'),
                         TYPE),
                                             (SELECT '4' AS '@Quantity',
                                             '1' AS '@LineNo',
                            'Box 4' AS 'UnitOfMeasure'
                     FOR XML PATH('ShipNoticeItem'),
                         TYPE)
                  FOR XML PATH('ShipNoticePortion'),
                      TYPE)

      FROM TEST2.PORDER
      WHERE POHNUM_0 = '2011302POH00000002'
        FOR XML PATH('ShipNoticeRequest'),
            TYPE )
   FROM TEST2.PORDER
   WHERE POHNUM_0 = '2011302POH00000002'
     FOR XML PATH('Request'),
         TYPE)
FROM TEST2.PORDER
WHERE POHNUM_0 = '2011302POH00000002'
  FOR XML PATH('?XML')
```

As you can see I have a question mark in the root field.  This fails with the error.
'?XML' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '?'(0x003F) is the first character at fault'.

My question is I need to be able to create the element with illegal characters in.  For example I also need another element surrounding the message which will be  "<!DOCTYPE>".  same scenario except this field has a exclamation mark.

Is this possible first off, and if so, can anyone help me finish it off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you maybe considered that the database layer isn't the most sensible place to try to construct a fully-fledged document like this (that isn't *actually* XML, and so the XML facilities are fighting you)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as part of the `For XML` however you can achieve this by using a combination of `FOR XML` and `NVARCHAR` manipulation.

So if you want to add a DocType (because you are in reality generating HTML), you can do it like this:

```
select '<!DOCTYPE html>'
+ cast(
(
    -- XML bit here
    -- Replace this with your XML query.

    select 
        A 
    from (
        select 'a1' as A 
        union select 'a2'
        ) a
        for xml path(''), root('Z'), type
)
 as nvarchar(Max))
```

However note that the result will **not** be XML suitable for SQL Server to re-import.

**Discussion**

XML and HTML are related (both being types of SGML), but not the same. HTML has features that XML does not, and XML has features that HTML does not.

You can write a subset of XML which is also a subset of HTML, which is often useful, but neither one is a subset of the other.